# Proper place for documenting implementation of convoluted code

Tags: python, code-documentation

For the past 3 months I have been working on a solo project in a company. Since for most part my Job consisted of coding I naturally have generated some amount of code ( ca. 2000 lines ) which I tried to comment as sensfully as I could.

In this project I have used lot of abstract python concepts, and in one part of the project I made heavy use of first-class functions. In this part I dynamically generate functions from other functions and save them for later use. Now even though my ideas are sound and easy to understand on paper, when code is read it is not understandable. Even though doc-strings are present my superiors have found it hard to follow the code even in my presence and step-by-step guidance. Now my question is regarding the documentation of such code. One example is as follows and is a piece of an enclosing function ( thus temp is an inner function) :

```
        def temp(time, var, ground_truth):
            mean = ground_truth(time)
            noisy = np.random.normal(mean, var)
            return noisy
        # ground_truth refers to vector of functions which are to be manipulated
        for _ in range(num_points + 1):
            new_tuple = list()
            for i in range(len(ground_truth)):
                partial = functools.partial(temp, var=variances[i], ground_truth=ground_truth[i])
                new_tuple.append(partial)
```

The code above takes a list of functions, and from each function of the list generates a new function which is sum of old function plus randomly generated normally distributed value.

My question regards the proper placement of documentation of implementation and idea-heavy details of the code. Would it be right to include such detailed documentation in docstring or should a completely separate document be created specially for such details regarding implementation? If a sepearate document should be created, what is the best way to it and are there any general guidelines?

Please keep in mind that this software needs to be handed over to my superiors and they need to continue its development.

Comment: I would suggest asking whoever are the intended readers of your code docs what they want the format to be. Some might like to read it with inline with the code, some are non-technical that they want instead to see diagrams with simple explanations, some want detailed textbook-like, API-like documentations. It depends.

Comment: To be sincere I was asking this question more in the spirit of learning about general conventions within programming community. Theoratically all options are equally good, but doing something "other way around" may not sit well when working on open projects.